# JDNI Active Directory, creating groups with scope

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, jndi

I'm trying to create some local groups in my AD but sadly if I set a groupType attribute in my context I only receive this exception

```
 Caused by: javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed 'groupType' attribute value; remaining name 'cn=localTestGroup1,ou=groups'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.encodeAttribute(LdapClient.java:951)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.add(LdapClient.java:999)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:393)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:197)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.bind(InitialDirContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$21.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:998)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:807)
        ... 36 more
```

It is possible that the value of the attribute is wrong. Or is my issue not solveable?

```
private void createGroup(String groupname, String groupOU, long groupType) {
        DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName();
        dn.add("ou", groupOU);
        dn.add("cn", groupname);

        DirContextAdapter ctx = new DirContextAdapter(dn);
        ctx.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "group" });
        ctx.setAttributeValue("groupType", groupType);
        ctx.setAttributeValue("sAMAccountName", groupname);

        ldapTemplate.bind(ctx);
    }

    public void createLocalGroup(String groupname, String groupOU) {
        createGroup(groupname, groupOU, -2147483646);
    }
```

For claryfication: I got this value `-2147483646` directly from the active directory. As you can mention I'm using `Spring Ldap 1.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the value for groupType as String not as long. This should solve your problem.

However the DN you are using looks strange. In my experience all Distinguished Names in AD ends at DC=something.

Comment: Sometimes its easier then it looks like. Cheers for this.